# How to set host within vue.config.js from .env file

Tags: vue.js

I have following setup within my app:

.env

```
VUE_APP_API_BASE_URL=http://localhost:8000/v5/
VUE_APP_HTTPS=true
VUE_APP_HOST=local.ei.run
```

I'm setting the env variables within the vue.config.js and however I am trying to work out a way to call them within there as follows

```
// vue.config.js
var webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    plugins: [
      new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env': {
          'API_BASE_URL': JSON.stringify(process.env.VUE_APP_API_BASE_URL),
          'HOST': JSON.stringify(process.env.VUE_APP_HOST)
        }
      })
    ]
  },
  // options...
  devServer: {
    open: process.platform === 'darwin',
    host: process.env.HOST,
    https: false,
    disableHostCheck: true
  }
}
```

So basically how can I set my host dynamically based off the env?

Comment: 1. Are your variables in `.env` file? Couse you are suggesting that they are in `.vue` :/ 2. Did you restart your server after those changes?

Comment: yes the first code block is .env (sorry for the confusion I've edited) I did a build and restart. however my app still starts http://localhost:8080